# TensorFlow RandomForest vs Deep learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, random-forest

I am using TensorFlow for training model which has 1 output for the 4 inputs. The problem is of regression.

I found that when I use RandomForest to train the model, it quickly converges and also runs well on the test data. But when I use a simple Neural network for the same problem, the loss(Random square error) does not converge. It gets stuck on a particular value.

I tried increasing/decreasing number of hidden layers, increasing/decreasing learning rate. I also tried multiple optimizers and tried to train the model on both normalized and non-normalized data.

I am new to this field but the literature that I have read so far vehemently asserts that the neural network should marginally and categorically work better than the random forest.

What could be the reason behind non-convergence of the model in this case?

Comment: If the training gets "stuck" in a specific configuration (or loss value), then it _does_ converge; the question is whether it converges to a useful state or not. It could also be that the improvement on each batch/epoch is so small it's not perceivable.

Answer (score 1):

If your model is not converging it means that the optimizer is stuck in a **local minima** in your loss function.
I don't know what optimizer you are using but try increasing the *momentum* or even the *learning rate* slightly.
Another strategy employed often is the **learning rate decay**, which reduces your learning rate by a factor every several epochs. This can also help you not get stuck in a local minima early in the training phase, while achieving maximum accuracy towards the end of training.

Otherwise you could try selecting an adaptive optimizer (adam, adagrad, adadelta, etc) that take care of the hyperparameter selection for you.

[This](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/) is a very good post comparing different optimization techniques.

Deep Neural Networks need a significant number of data to perform adequately. Be sure you have **lots** of training data or your model will **overfit**.

Answer (score 0):

A useful rule for beginning training models, is not to begin with the more complex methods, for example, a Linear model, which you will be able to understand and debug more easily.

In case you continue with the current methods, some ideas:

- Check the initial weight values (init them with a normal distribution)
- As a previous poster said, diminish the learning rate
- Do some additional checking on the data, check for NAN and outliers, the current models could be more sensitive to noise. Remember, garbage in, garbage out.